# NSDateFormatter locale is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

I am using the following code to get the `NSString` from date

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterLongStyle;
df.timeStyle = kCFDateFormatterNoStyle;
df.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;
[df setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[df  setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSString *dateString=[df stringFromDate:myDate];
```

But it displaying like 'Today','Yesterday' even after changing Locale.I want to display the localized language of that also ?

Comment: have you tried this code from the simulator or the device?

Comment: `NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterLongStyle;
    df.timeStyle = kCFDateFormatterNoStyle;
    df.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;
    [df setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ru_RU"]];
    [df  setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];` this works like a charm. I'm getting russian names of 'Today' = 'Сегодня'

Comment: what you mean `after changing Locale`? Give us full code. What language setup on your current locale?

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and created this:

```
NSDate *yesterday;
NSTimeInterval interval;

NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

[cal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
       startDate:&yesterday
        interval:&interval
         forDate:[NSDate date]];

yesterday = [yesterday dateByAddingTimeInterval:-interval];



NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterLongStyle;
df.timeStyle = kCFDateFormatterNoStyle;
df.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;

[@[[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_DE"], [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es_ES"],[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSLocale *locale, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [df setLocale:locale];
    [df  setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    NSString *dateString=[df stringFromDate:yesterday];
    NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
}];
```

It outputs correctly

```
Gestern
ayer
Yesterday
```

Your problem must lay else-where.

<sub>Tested within a command-line program</sub>

---

Make sure that after you changed the language on device/simulator you kill the app completely before you open it again.

Comment: Could be, as @Ilario suggests, simulator vs. device.

Answer (score -2):

Hi I write this Function for LocalTime it Takes input of date as String and covert to Local Time String. May it help you

```
+(NSString*)LocalTimeWitheDateString:(NSString*)dateString{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
    [formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date =[formatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSTimeZone *localTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    [formatter setTimeZone:localTimeZone];
    NSString *LnewTimeZoneDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    return LnewTimeZoneDateString;
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.